# Which embedding layer does skip-gram use?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, embedding

[image]

In Skip-gram, it has pairs of a focused word and context words. Then, it outputs each pair is correct or wrong pairs.
In contrast to CBOW, Skip-gram uses two embedding layer. After training, which embedding layer should be used?

In below examples in Keras, it looks using first (focused word embedding, not context one) embedding layer.

https://github.com/nzw0301/keras-examples/blob/master/Skip-gram-with-NS.ipynb